# Mathematica 8 constantly crashing when I rotate 3D graphics

Tags: 11.10, graphics, intel-graphics

[Mathematica 8](http://www.wolfram.com/) is consistently crashing on Ubuntu 11.10 when I rotate 3D graphics.

On Ubuntu 11.04 it did not.

I have [Intel GMA 900 integrated graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_GMA_900#GMA_900).

**Did anyone encounter the same problem and manage to come up with a solution** (before a compatible version of Mms is released)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem.  The response from Wolfram was to check
my open source video driver and maybe try an older one/newer one.

They recommend using `Mathematica -mesa` which seems to fix the
problem, but the graphics performace seems to be slower.

Comment: The next question then will be: how to switch to a different driver (preferably without messing up the system and being stuck with command line only)?

Comment: The -mesa option is indeed a very usable workaround (the performance hit is not enormous from what I noticed).  I'd still be interested in how to try a newer or older driver.